# File Path/size in C#

Tags: filesystems, clr, directory

How to get the File Directory of a file (C:\myfolder\subfoler\mydoc.pdf). I also want to add the size of the subfolders, and finally the main folder size. This is for a .NET CLR that I need to integrate with SQL Server 2005 for a SSRS report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(VS.80).aspx), to get only the directory path of the file:

```
using System.IO;
string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\myfolder\subfolder\mydoc.pdf");
// directoryName now contains "C:\myfolder\subfolder"
```

For calculating the directory and subdirectory size, you can do something like this:

```
public static long DirSize(DirectoryInfo d) 
{    
    long Size = 0;    
    // Add file sizes.
    FileInfo[] fis = d.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo fi in fis) 
    {      
        Size += fi.Length;    
    }
    // Add subdirectory sizes.
    DirectoryInfo[] dis = d.GetDirectories();
    foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dis) 
    {
        Size += DirSize(di);   
    }
    return(Size);  
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with the long Data Type when integrating this with SQL Server Assembly. Any replacement for long that is compatible with SQL Server?

Comment: Long is what you should use in your C# code - you need to find the most appropriate data type to match it to in the db. I can't check now, but I'm positive there's an appropriate 64 bit integer type.

Comment: I'm getting error "CREATE FUNCTION for "DirSize" failed because T-SQL and CLR types for parameter "@dir" do not match."

My CREATE Function Statement is:

CREATE FUNCTION DirSize(@dir VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS BIGINT EXTERNAL NAME getdirsize.ShowDirSize.DirSize

getdirsize is the name of my sql assembly

Comment: It looks like the datatype problem is with the "dir" parameter, presumably the string path, rather than with the number. Are you passing it the right thing?

Comment: @Khoth
What Data Type is compatible with DirectoryInfo?